# How do I take 2 values during trigger change and assign to each select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, triggers, jquery-select2

My html code like this :

```
<div class="row"> 
    ...
    <div class="col s12 m8 input-field">
        <select id="dropdown_hospital" class="browser-default auto-complete-element required">
            <option value="">Select hospital</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    ....
    <div class="col s12 m8 input-field">
        <select id="dropdown_specialist" class="browser-default auto-complete-element">
            <option value="">Select specialist</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    ...
    <div class="col s12 m8 input-field">
        <select id="dropdown_doctor" name="dropdown_doctor" class="browser-default auto-complete-element required">
            <option value="">Select doctor</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript code like this :

```
function getComplete({ doctor_id, elementDoctor }) {
    $.ajax({
        url: api,
        data: { doctorId: doctor_id },
        ...
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result.data, function (index, item) {
                var doctoritem = '<option data-hosp="' + item.hospital_id + '" data-spec="' + item.specialist_id + '"value=' + item.doctor_id + '>' + item.doctor_name + '</option>';
                $(doctoritem).appendTo(elementDoctor);
            });
        },
        ...
    }).done(function () {
        elementDoctor.select2();
        $('#dropdown_doctor').val(doctor_id).trigger('change');
        var h = $('#dropdown_doctor option:selected').data('hosp');
        var s = $('#dropdown_doctor option:selected').data('spec');
        $('#dropdown_specialist').val(s);
        $('#dropdown_hospital').val(h).trigger('change');
        ...
    });
};
```

when the getComplete method is called, it will call api and display the doctor's data in the option by docter id

when ajax is done, there will be a trigger process

my problem here is that only hospitals and doctors have been selected, while specialist have not selected

why the specialist was not selected?

Comment: trigger change?

Comment: @guradio Yes of course

Comment: Is there no one to can help me?

Comment: add or call the change event did you try this already?

Comment: @guradio I had try it. But it does not work. that's why I'm asking here

Comment: can you check the value of `s` maybe its not a value from the select list of the specialists

Comment: @guradio it's true.  it's a value from the select list of the specialists